# Animation Nodes move certain mesh vertices

Tags: animation, node-editor, vertices, animation-nodes

[image]

I would like to move certain vertices from an animated mesh object along its normals to create a new mesh (or use face normals and create new point). Is it possible to choose certain vertices and also to vary the length of the normal vector.

I am new to Animation nodes and I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 6):

the "Object Mesh Data" Node has a hidden input called "Vertex Normals". Press n to open the properties panel in the node editor and activate the output by clicking on the little eye icon.

[image]

you can then use a vector math node to scale the vertices along their normals. shuffle the vertex list and remove all but the first vertices.

That's it.

[image]

Parameters to control the output:

- **Scaling factor** of the first vector math node: there you can control how far away each point is from the base mesh
- **Node Seed** of the shuffle list node: shuffles the list in another order, other vertices get deleted from the end of the vertex list
- **end** of the slice list node: controls the amount of vertices that don't get deleted

**Bonus**
node setup with splines (like in your reference image):

[image]

Let me know if you need anything else or a deeper explanation